# Scrapy banning problems

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping, scrapy-splash

I am using scrapy 1.12 for crawling classified sites.

The crawler in the localhost is working but the server(centos) isn't working.

I am using, randomuseragent and randomproxy.

my settings.py file

```
BOT_NAME = 'xx(https://xx.com)'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['xyz_crawler.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'xyz_crawler.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'xyz_crawler.pipelines.XmlWriterPipeline': 800
    }
# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent

USER_AGENT = 'null'


# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 8


# Retry many times since proxies often fail
RETRY_TIMES = 1
# Retry on most error codes since proxies fail for different reasons
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#   'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}

RANDOM_UA_FILE = "xyz_crawler/useragents.txt"
# Proxy list containing entries like
# http://host1:port
# http://username:password@host2:port
# http://host3:port
# ...
PROXY_LIST = 'xyz_crawler/proxies.txt'

# Proxy mode
# 0 = Every requests have different proxy
# 1 = Take only one proxy from the list and assign it to every requests
# 2 = Put a custom proxy to use in the settings
PROXY_MODE = 0 

# If proxy mode is 2 uncomment this sentence :
#CUSTOM_PROXY = "http://host1:port"


DOWNLOADER_CLIENTCONTEXTFACTORY = 'xyz_crawler.contextfactory.CustomContextFactory'
# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY=3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN=16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP=16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED=False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED=False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'xyz_crawler.middlewares.MyCustomSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
#   'xyz_crawler.middlewares.TestDownloader': 100,
#}
```

Proxy IP address and useragent are the same in both places.

I tried COOKIES_ENABLED:false but it didn't work anyway.

Why that is not working?

Comment: What delays are you adding between each hit on the same server?

Comment: The null `USER_AGENT` is probably going to be a problem.